# UNIX AND LINUX EXPLANATION

Tags: linux, unix

I want to know what exactly UNIX and Linux are? Whether both are OS  or Linux is kernel on UNIX OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix and  Linux both are OS ,Linux have Linux kernel ,and Unix have Unix kernel.Linux is developed by Open Source development i.e. through sharing and collaboration of code and features through forums etc and it is distributed by various vendors.Unix systems are divided into various other flavors, mostly developed by AT&T as well as various commercial vendors and non-profit organizations.
[following link differentiate both OS](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Linux_vs_Unix) [This Wikipedia of Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)[This Wikipedia of Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)
all this link give you very clear idea of Linux and Unix